# .NET MVC Route on Menu Controller to Redirect to specific controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm having the following problem:

When I click on Menu Item Button on my View, I reach `MenuController` method `RedirectAction`:

```
public ActionResult RedirectAction(string actionRedirect, int moduloAtual)
    {
        TempData["ModuloAtual"] = moduloAtual;
        var botaoVoltarSubMenu = Request["voltar"];
        ViewBag.baseUsuario = Request["baseUsuario"];
        var redirect = string.Empty;

        if (botaoVoltarSubMenu == "1")
        {
            redirect = $"{Url.Content("~")}{actionRedirect}?baseUsuario={ViewBag.baseUsuario}";
        }
        else
        {

            redirect = $"{Url.Content("~")}{actionRedirect}";
        }

        return Redirect(redirect);
    }
```

What I'm facing is, after `return Redirect(redirect)` the URL on my browser shows this (my actionRedirect value is `Notas`:

```
http://localhost:40169/Menu/RedirectAction?actionRedirect=Notas&moduloAtual=40000
```

and doesn't redirect to my /Notas Controller.

Does this have something to do with RouteConfig?

**My RouteConfig.cs:**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{intID}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", intID = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong here? I just want to Redirect to the Controller which has the same value as my `actionRedirect` parameter name.

Please, help! And thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want such a complexity in your code for simple menu redirect? It sounds like you just need to redirect to specific controller/action with our without action parameter(s).

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Notas", new { moduloAtual = 4000 })">Notas</a>
```

**Update:**
As for your current implementation, seems like you can not access `RedirectAction` action as you are providing wrong parameter name, instead of `modulo` it should be `moduloAtual`:

```
<div class="box-button text-center hvr-grow-shadow" onclick="window.location = '@Url.Action("RedirectAction", "Menu", new {actionRedirect = obj, moduloAtual = idModulo})'">
```

Comment: Actually I got this system this way, the method already implemented but for some reason not working. This is my div on the menu that calls the controller method: <div class="box-button text-center hvr-grow-shadow" onclick="window.location = '@Url.Action("RedirectAction", "Menu", new {actionRedirect = obj, modulo= idModulo})'">

Comment: It's a dynamic menu created with database modules. So for each click I have a different object and moduleId that I pass to the MenuController to handle for me, and then redirect.

Comment: @RodrigoAssis it makes sense. See my updated answer, found one issue in your implementation that might prohibiting accessing your action

Answer (score 0):

The `Redirect` method does not redirect to a controller, it redirects to a URL string. `RedirectToAction` will allow you specify an action and a controller, but you don't seem to have an actual action on the controller being specified.

The following will redirect to the `Index` action on the controller specified in the `actionRedirect` parameter:

```cs
public ActionResult RedirectAction(string actionRedirect, int moduloAtual)
{
    TempData["ModuloAtual"] = moduloAtual;
    var botaoVoltarSubMenu = Request["voltar"];
    ViewBag.baseUsuario = Request["baseUsuario"];

    if (botaoVoltarSubMenu == "1")
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", actionRedirect, new { baseUsario = ViewBag.baseUsario });
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", redirectAction);
}
```

If `actionRedirect` is the action, and it should always use the `Notas` controller, change to:

```cs
return RedirectToAction(redirectAction, "Notas", new { baseUsario = ViewBag.baseUsario }); 

return RedirectToAction(redirectAction, "Notas");
```

For each above respectively.